# Simple Time-Clock does not work with no errors

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I'm having some trouble with this code I wrote. It's supposed to create a digital time-clock for my website.

If you're wondering why CPGS is in my functions/variable names it's because its a abbreviation for my website name :)

Also, I am getting NO console errors from FireBug and my JSLint confirms that my code is vaild.

Here's the code:

```
    (function() {
    function CpgsClock() {
        this.cpgsTime = new Date();
        this.cpgsHour = this.cpgsTime.getHours();
        this.cpgsMin = this.cpgsTime.getMinutes();
        this.cpgsDay = this.cpgsTime.getDay();
        this.cpgsPeriod = "";
    }

    CpgsClock.prototype.checker = function() {
        if (this.cpgsHour === 0) {
            this.cpgsPeriod = " AM";
            this.cpgsHour = 12;
        } else if (this.cpgsHour <= 11) {
            this.cpgsPeriod = " AM";
        } else if (this.cpgsHour === 12) {
            this.cpgsPeriod = " PM";
        } else if (this.cpgsHour <= 13) {
            this.cpgsPeriod = " PM";
            this.cpgsHour -= 12;
        }
    };

    CpgsClock.prototype.setClock = function() {
        document.getElementById('cpgstime').innerHTML = "" + this.cpgsHour + ":" + this.cpgsMin + this.cpgsPeriod + "";
    };

    var cpgsclock = new CpgsClock();
    setInterval(function() {
        cpgsclock.setClock();
        cpgsclock.checker();
    }, 1000);

})();
```

So setClock method works fine. But the checker won't do anything. As you can see it checks for the time and sets it to AM and PM accordingly. It doesn't do that for me.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not updating the clock in your setInterval...

```
CpgsClock.prototype.update = function() {
    this.cpgsTime = new Date();
    this.cpgsHour = this.cpgsTime.getHours();
    this.cpgsMin = this.cpgsTime.getMinutes();
    this.cpgsDay = this.cpgsTime.getDay();
    this.cpgsPeriod = "";
};
```

And in your `setInterval` :

```
setInterval(function() {
    cpgsclock.update();
    cpgsclock.checker();
    cpgsclock.setClock();
}, 1000);
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qmSua/1/